Adding ++ctrl+enter++ key combination in bash (to allow for nvim enter key combinations)
I'm trying to make the ++ctrl+enter+ key work in nvim to be able to create a new line above in incert mode without leaving <ESC>oi similar to vscode but the following don't work:
keymap("i", "<C-Enter>", "<ESC>oi", opts)
keymap("i", "<C-S-Enter>", "<ESC>Oi", opts)

hitting read to see what code ++enter++ yields for bash doesn't give positive results about that either as it seem to behave like the regular enter key even with the ++ctrl++ ++shilf++ combos I guess something needs to be edited for the readline or xkb to make that work but even mapping ++ctrl+enter++ to something like "ab"(natively working keycombo with chords) would suffice if the ++enter++'d problematic for the nvim mapper for some reason...
Any tips / directions of how to make this work?

From the point of view of the terminal, Enter is the same as Ctrl-M (or Ctrl-J, forgot which), Tab is the same as Ctrl-I, Esc is the same as Ctrl-], etc. So, Ctrl-Tab is the same as Ctrl-Ctrl-I, which is just Ctrl-I, which is just Tab. The same for Enter, Return, Esc, etc.

Uhu ok that makes sense tested it noe with the read but is there a way to easly bind that to another secuance of keys and then(the next step) tell nvim keymap manager to handle it accordingly?

Not really, not without having a terminal emulator which supports it (there might be some, but none that I use). Find some other key combination.

yeah but it's very convinient for the mind to use the same key that creates new lines in almost all tryping apps to be used to make new lines in different ways quicky for programming in combination with other mod keys.

Then your best bet is to try different terminal emulators until you find one which allows you to remap Ctrl-Enter

no way, I'm sticking to legacy bash and sinning with tmux guess I'll have to find the hard way, the linux way.
